# How can I search an array of subdocument fields that match a given array

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection of recipes that match this format:

```
{
  title: "a recipe",
  ingredients: [
    {
      description: "sugar",
      amount: "1 cup"
    },
    {
      description: "flour",
      amount: "2 cups"
    }
  ] 
}
```

If given an array such as `["sugar", "butter"]`, what is the best way to return all recipes that have an ingredient whose description is in the given array?

Comment: Give an example and what have you tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB unwinds the arrays while querying. So this query ought to do it.

```
{'ingredients.description':{$in:["sugar", "butter"]}}
```